# How to handle exception in Struts

Tags: exception, struts

How can we handle exceptions in Struts? Please share the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use log4j to log the exceptions,
- Never use System.out.println in struts application to catch exceptions, as it is expensive ,
- Tutorials for log4j>  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html
- to handle the errors:

in struts project to handle the error objet by using ActionError object and to handle the errors by using ActionErrors object.

for suppose

```
ActionError ae1=new ActionError("err.one");

ActionError ae2=new ActionError("err.two");

Action Errors aes=new ActionErrors();

aes.add(ae1);

aes.add(ae2);

saveErrors(request,aes);//store the errors object in request object
```

to handle exception:

1)using try and cach blocks

2)using declarative exception handling technique

to handle the exceptions by using global exceptons tag in struts-config.xml

whenever that exception will be came it executes the gen.jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

The following URL should help http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch18-Exception_Handling.htm